# Carregar Window Form dentro Container VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Opa

Tenho uma função para abertura de forms dentro de um container geral.

```
Function carrega_form(ByRef ctl As Control, ByRef frm As Form)
    If ctl IsNot Nothing AndAlso frm IsNot Nothing Then
        frm.TopLevel = False
        frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        frm.Visible = True
        ctl.Controls.Add(frm)
    End If
End Function
```

Para chama-la uso:

```
carrega_form(container, New frm_content_cadastro_botoes)
```

Senha que o `container`fica num form principal, o que tenho que fazer é apenas carregar outros forms dentro deste container, o problema é que isso ocorre apenas uma vez, ou seja, ao executar a função o form é aberto, mas, ao executar novamente não acontece nada.

Tentei antes de chamar a função usar: `Me.hide`, mas, ainda não chama o form como deveria.

Se usar a chamada para containers diferentes funciona.

O objeto container é um Panel

Answer (score 0):

Os comentários explicam todas alterações que fiz. Alguma delas pode resolver seu problema.

```
'                                              | você não precisa de uma
'                                              | referência para uma forma
'                                              | que está chamando sem
'                                              | referência
' Isso não retorna nada, então                 |
' não precisa ser uma Function                \ /
Public Sub carrega_form(ByRef ctl As Control, ByVal frm As Form)
    ' Verificação nula sempre no início do código
    ' Vamos economizar processador, galera
    If ctl Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Remove os controles antigos
    For i As Integer = 0 To ctrl.Controls.Count - 1
        ctrl.Controls.RemoveAt(i)
    Next
    ' Converte implícitamente a form para control
    Dim c As Control = frm
    ' Não precisamos mais da form
    frm.Dispose()
    ' Isso já define local e tamanho do controle.
    c.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    ' Será visível?
    c.Visible = True
    ' Adiciona o controle.
    ctl.Controls.Add(c)
End Sub
```